# Php SOAP - Document length exceeds allowed threshold

Tags: php, soap

Формирую SOAP клиент, делаю запрос

```
$req = [
                        'account' => env('TEXTKERNEL_ACCOUNT'),
                        'username' => env('TEXTKERNEL_USERNAME'),
                        'password' => env('TEXTKERNEL_PASSWORD'),
                        'filename' => "cv.txt",
                        'fileContent' => base64_encode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/cv.txt'))
                        ];
    
                    $client = new \SoapClient(env('TEXTKERNEL_STAGE'), [
                        'trace' => true,
                        'exceptions' => true
                    ]);
                    var_dump($client->extract($req));die;
```

В ответ получаю:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": "com.textkernel.soap.ProcessDocumentException: TEXTRACTOR_ERROR: com.textkernel.txtor_ui.actions.ActionException: Processing failed; type=TEXTRACTOR_ERROR; txtorErrorCode=SERVER_ERROR; task=NORMALIZATION; url=txtor-tcp://tkml-models.a:50200; step=1; recoverable=false; txtorError: ERROR: 400 Document length exceeds allowed threshold based on average number of characters per line. correlationid=E4D4E334FBDA0F2476777652329F2F5D_1602161208340"
}
```

Решается ли эта проблема на уровне настроек SOAP клиента? Если переменная `fileContent` - небольшая строка - ответ приходит нормально.
Если такой же запрос делать через `cUrl` - ответ тоже успешный

Comment: Эта ошибка из библиотеки, обрабатывающей запрос, смотрите её документацию, нам остаётся только гадать что в ней так как в стандартном SoapClient или SoapServer такого нет.

Comment: Я думал это стандартный клиент. Смотрел сюда https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Клиент может и стандартный, но ошибка у вас от сервера, к которому делается запрос.